# SWIG + TCL flags

Tags: tcl, swig

Will the ownership of a pointer last only in the block in which we set the `-acquire` flag for it?

Eg.:

```
{
        {
               $xyz -acquire
        }
}
```

Comment: TCL doesn't have the syntax you think it does, you may want to try reading about TCL syntax

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Tcl doesn't define blocks with `{`/`}`. The scope is defined by the procedure call or namespace.

Secondly, Tcl commands are always defined to have lifetime that corresponds to the namespace that owns them; they are never<sup>†</sup> scoped to a procedure call. They must be manually disposed one way or another; there are two ways to do this manual disposal: calling `$xyz -delete` or `rename $xyz ""` (or to anything else that is the empty string). Frankly, I prefer the first method.

But if you do want the lifespan to be tied to a procedure call, that's actually quite possible to do. It just requires some extra code:

```
proc tieLifespan args {
    upvar 1 "____lifespan handle" v
    if {[info exists v]} {
        trace remove variable v unset $v
        set args [concat [lindex $v 1] $args]
    }
    set v [concat Tie-Garbage-Collect $args]
    trace add variable v unset $v
}
proc Tie-Garbage-Collect {handles var dummy1 dummy2} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    foreach handle $handles {
        # According to SWIG docs, this is how to do explicit destruction
        $handle -delete
        # Alternatively: rename $handle ""
    }
}
```

That you'd use like this in the scope that you want to tie `$xyz`'s life to:

```
tieLifespan $xyz
# You can register multiple objects at once too
```

And that's it. When the procedure (or procedure-like entity if you're using Tcl 8.5 or later) exits, the tied object will be deleted. It's up to you to decide if that's what you really want; if you later disown the handle, you probably ought to *not* use tying.

---

<sup>†</sup> Well, hardly ever; some extensions do nasty things. Discount this statement as it *doesn't apply* to SWIG-generated code!

Comment: hi Donal thanks for your expert advice. But I am stuck to something and it is really pissing me off. Actually I have used SWIG to call methods in a c++ library. And I am calling a C++ method that returns me List of pointers. In this case swig returns me pointer to that list. And I am extracting all elements from that list pointer by calling list_at and list_size methods present in wrap.cxx. And after extracting those pointers when I am doing "cget -thisown" of those pointer which I have extracted I am getting 0 instead of 1. So please kindly help me on this.